# Flutter: Custom Drawer that always stays open

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, dart

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfbUN.png)

How can I implement a navigation drawer with a custom shape like this on Flutter.
(see image)The curve next the "Sign In" button must change as we change the pages. Can anyone help me with this. Thank you

Comment: if it **always** stays open, why you need `Drawer` at all? use `Material` / `Container` / whatever

Comment: Yes that's alright too. How can I draw that shape on flutter though(i'm sorry, i'm a noob)

Answer (score 1):

Since desktop support is out now I wanted such a widget too... So I made one!

https://pub.dev/packages/side_navigation

Check it out and see if that is what your looking for.